# How to I exclude a certain value from the output of this code?

Tags: python, psse

So my code is basically scanning a notepad .txt document and showing the output of all P.U. voltage values below 0.8 and returns a message of "faliure" if one is found. The problem is, there is at least one value in each file at exactly 0.0. This is a nuisance value that I would like to exclude. The output file is saying the file fails if it finds this value because it is below the 0.8 threshold, but this is a null value.

```
timeForVoltageRecovery = 11.0    
acceptableVoltagePU = 0.8

for channel in data:
        if float(channel['time']) > timeForVoltageRecovery:
            isVoltageGood = True
            keys = channel.keys()
            keys.sort()
            volts = {}
            for key in keys:
                words = key.split(" ")
                if words[0] == "VOLT":
                        volts[float(channel[key])] = key.strip()

            voltsKeys = volts.keys()
            voltsKeys.sort()
            for k in range(10):
                if float(channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]]) < acceptableVoltagePU:
                    isVoltageGood = False

            if isVoltageGood:
                outfile.write("\nAt time %s, this scenario passed voltage recovery criteria of 0.8 PU!\n" % (channel['time']))
            else:
                outfile.write("\n\t***** BAD: At Time %s, this scenario failed voltage recovery criteria of .8 PU :{ *****\n\n" % (channel['time']))
                outfile.write("the lowest 10 voltages in order are:\n")
                for k in range(10):
                    outfile.write(  "\t" + volts[voltsKeys[k]] + " -> " + channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]] + "\n" )               

            outfile.write("\n")
            break
```

Does anyone know how I can still scan values below 0.8, but exclude 0.0 in my scan?

thank you.

I tried to make a lower voltage threshold value of 0.01. From here you could do an "if" statement where the acceptablevoltagePU has to be between 0.8 and 0.01. Something like this could definitely get the job done. I am not exactly sure how to code this.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your dataset? This will help everyone see what might be causing the issue.

Comment: The scan is searching for the keyword "VOLT" in the file. Here are some of the lines it is scanning  6177    0.87851     VOLT  [x1]  0.40877     VOLT  [x6]
  6179    0.40802     VOLT  [x2]  0.67658     VOLT  [x5]
  6181    0.67657     VOLT  [x3]  0.72586     VOLT  [x4]

Comment: Please don't put it in the comments. Comments don't render new lines. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to [Kundan Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20492768/kundan-krishna)'s answer, you can do like

```py
# your other code ...

voltsKeys = volts.keys()
voltsKeys.sort()
for k in range(10):
  currentVoltage = float(channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]]) # read and cast only once
  if currentVoltage < acceptableVoltagePU and currentVoltage != 0.0:
    isVoltageGood = False

# your other code ...
```

Doing this way reduces the number of time you are reading from the various dictionary (`channel`, `volt`, `voltKeys`) as well as the casting being done.

---

Additionally, I see that your code does not really follow Python's [naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables). In general, they should be lowercase words separated by underscore.

So for example,

| Your code | Python Convention |
| --- | --- |
| `timeForVoltageRecovery` | `time_for_voltage_recovery` |
| `acceptableVoltagePU` | `acceptable_voltage_PU` |
| `isVoltageGood` | `is_voltage_good` |

Answer (score 0):

I am on phone so code editor doesn't work. But what you can do if `0.0` is always a `false` flag just use this

`if float(channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]]) < acceptableVoltagePU and float(channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]]) != 0.0` in your if statement.

Comment: Thank you! Am I doing this right? if(AND(float(channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]]) < acceptableVoltagePU, float(channel[volts[voltsKeys[k]]]) != 0.0 :
                    isVoltageGood = False

Comment: No use "and"  between the two conditions and "and" should be in lowercase. The conditions don't need to be nested they just need to separated with and.